# Integrating absolute complex exponential function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How would you integrate this:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} |e^{it}| dt
$$

I use the identity $e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$ but that gets me nowhere.

Also, does $e^{it}$ and $e^{2it}$ have the same range?

Comment: $|e^{it}|=1$ for all real $t$...

Comment: You mean $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{it} dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:*

The absolute value of a complex number is also:

$$|a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

What do we know about $cos^2(t) + sin^2(t)$?

Comment: If the op doesn't get it from this hint, they need to seriously consider dropping the course because it's not going to be possible to pass it!

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: He could just be having an off day. His other questions lead to believe he's ready.

Comment: @Bair I get it now! I was just confused by the absolute sign. Thank you!

Comment: @Bair. Btw, what is meant by the period of an imaginary exponential function? I just encountered this term for the first time and couldn't understand what I found. Thank you.

Comment: @user90593: I have not seen the term before either. Sorry.